# In ingredient lists, does "lime" mean the fruit or the chemical?

Tags: food-science, nutrient-composition, lime

Ingredient lists on packaged foods sometimes list "lime".  Does this refer to the [citrus fruit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lime_%28fruit%29), or to the chemical [calcium hydroxide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_hydroxide)?

As an example, [Mission Organics White Corn Tortilla Chips](http://www.missionmenus.com/en/products/view/mission-organics-white-corn-tortilla-chips-11-oz) list "trace of lime" as the last ingredient.  This could indicate some part (or juice) of the citrus fruit, included as a seasoning (common in Mexican cuisine).  On the other hand, there is a [process for preparing corn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nixtamalization) (*maize* in some dialects) which involves cooking it in a calcium hydroxide solution.  So if these chips are made using this process, "trace of lime" could refer to calcium hydroxide residues.  Which is meant?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calcium hydroxide is pretty much insoluble, so it's hard to get every last bit of it out after nixtamalizing. A trace always remains. If the maker were selling lime flavored tortilla chips, [which *are* sold](https://www.google.com/search?q=lime%20flavored%20tortillas&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=lime%20flavored%20tortilla%20chips) the ingredient list would say something like "lime extract" or "natural lime flavor".